# Analog Input on ATTiny85 not working?

Tags: attiny

EDIT: SOLVED

As the title, I cannot get any of the analog Inputs on the ATTiny85 to read off of a POT. For debugging and testing, it is currently hooked up to a shift register with 8 LEDs. This setup works fine when just outputting an int vale. At this point I'm a little lost.

I have very little experience with ATTiny so I'm betting its something silly.
POT is hooked up with one side on +5VDC and the center tap on the analog read pin.

```
int data = PB0;
int clock = PB2;
int latch = PB3;
int ledState = 0;
int POT = PB4;

int PWM = 255;
int LED;

const int ON = HIGH;
const int OFF = LOW;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(data, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(latch, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(POT, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  LED = analogRead(POT);
  LED = map(LED, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  updateLEDs(LED);
  delay(1000);
}




void updateLEDs(int value){
  digitalWrite(latch, LOW);     //Pulls the chips latch low
  shiftOut(data, clock, MSBFIRST, value); //Shifts out the 8 bits to the shift register
  digitalWrite(latch, HIGH);   //Pulls the latch high displaying the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I was right about it being a silly thing. I didn't have the other side of the POT hooked to ground. Works now!